# Is there any performance issue if i query in mysql multiple partitions at once compared to querying same data without partitions?

Tags: mysql, partitioning, database-partitioning

I have transactions table in which it is partitioned by client ids(currently will have 4 clients, so 4 partitions). Now if I query for client id in (1,2) is there any performance issue compared to using same query with out partitions on the table? 
I hear that for each partition mysql will maintain separate file system, so querying in partitioned table need to open multiple files internally and query will slow down. Is this correct?

Comment: try it out and see what its doing

Comment: Please don't double tag RDBMS.  SQL Server and MySQL often require different answers to the same question.

Comment: Are you asking about both MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server? I see you specifically called out MySQL in your question but also have a sql-server tag. I can say there is no performance hit with a SQL Server version of the query but performance will probably be similar the a single table with a clustered index.

Comment: only mysql not microsoft sql server

Answer (score 0):

`PARTITION BY LIST`?  `BY RANGE`?  `BY HASH`?  other?  It can make a big difference.

Use `EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT ...` to see if it is doing any "pruning".  If it is not, then partitioning is a performance drag for that query.

In general, there are very few cases where partitioning provides any performance benefit.  It sounds like your case will not benefit from partitioning.  Think of it this way...  First, it must decide which partition(s) to look in, then it will dig into the index to finish locating the row(s).  Without partitioning, the first step is avoided, hence *potentially* faster.

If you grow to hundreds of "clients", hence "partitions, then the pruning is inefficient since each partition is essentially a "table".

See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint for a list of the only 4 use cases that I have found for partitioning.